# error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::pair<const int,

Tags: c++, boost, std, stdstring, stdset

So I've been going at this for the past few days and can't seem to get my head around it any and all help is so very much appreciated and grateful of.

Thank you so very much.

Error Code:

```
  /usr/local/include/boost/assign/list_of.hpp:164:20: error: no matching
  constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::pair<const int,
  std::__1::set<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
  std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
  std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > > >'
  return Container( begin(), end()  );
```

I've tried everything that I'm aware of but can't seem to come around with a fix.

Header File :

```
typedef std::map<int, std::set<std::string> > MapRegisteredPeople;
```

Source :

```
registeredPeople = (MapRegisteredPeople) {
    boost::assign::map_list_of
    (0,     std::set<std::string>() )
    (1, boost::assign::list_of<std::string>
                (“FOO1”) 
                (“FOO2”)
    .convert_to_container<std::set<std::string> >())
    };
```

I expected this to compile and proceed without errors but alas, would be wonderful if a lovely soul help me out here. Thank you so very much.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Noted with thanks. 